# Remove Unused Functions in AutoIt Script with PowerShell

Tags: regex, powershell, powershell-2.0, autoit

Alrighty..

So I am editing an AutoIt script that has a lot of unused functions in it. The original author saw fit to add all the functions from his/her includes files.

At first I tried to use the tools within AutoIt/SciTe to remove unused functions however for some freakish reason this rendered the script/compiled file useless. So now I am thinking it would be best to write a function remover.

Here is what I have so far:
Search for lines with "Func _" count number of times that function appears in the file. If 1 time then Select String

```
$FileName=".\FILENAME.au3"
$File=Get-Content $FileName
$Funcs=$File|Select-String "Func _"
foreach ($Func in $Funcs) {
    $FuncName=$Func.ToString().Split('( ')[1]
    $Count=($File|Select-String $FuncName | Measure-Object).Count
    if ($count -eq 1) {
        $File|Select-String "Func _" $FuncName
    }
}
```

What I would like to do is remove the function, likely with regex. So something like:
REMOVE "Func _"$func * "EndFunc"

The trouble has been that this is a search that spans multiple lines, from Func _NAMEOFFUCTION to EndFunc. Its unclear to me if regex in PowerShell can even do this. Not all regex implementations seem to be able to span a search across lines. Is regex even the answer? I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

When you use Get-Content in PowerShell 1.0 or 2.0 you can only get back an array of strings - one for each line. This isn't going to work when you need a regex to span multiple lines.  Use this approach to read the file as a single string:

```
$FileContent = [io.file]::ReadAllText($FileName)
```

If you are on PowerShell V3 you can use the `-Raw` parameter to read the file as a single string:

```
$FileContent = Get-Content $FileName -Raw
```

Then when you use Select-String you will need to modify the regex to enable singleline `s` (and probably multiline `m`) mode e.g.:

```
$FileContent | Select-String "(?smi)$FuncName" -AllMatches
```

Note the `i` is there to be case-insensitive.  Use the `-AllMatches` parameter to match multiple function definitions within a file.

Comment: That doesn't sound right.  I'm not fluent in PowerShell, but I do know regexes, and I don't see how Singleline *or* Multiline mode can be relevant.  In fact, it's probably best to treat `$FuncName` as a literal string instead of a regex, by adding the `-SimpleMatch` parameter.

Comment: If you need a regex to span multiple lines then it is typically pretty pertinent to have `.` match newlines (ie singleline mode).  Multiline is only important if you need to match to the beginning (or end) of a line within the string.  It also important to have the lines you want to match against in a single string.

Comment: BTW you posited whether PowerShell can do regex across lines.  I'm saying that it can. :-)

Comment: I know what the modes do, what I'm saying is you don't need them here.  I mean, `$FuncName` is just a name, isn't it?  Something like `_MyFunc`?  The whole *function* may span multiple lines, but the function's *name* won't.  And if the name happens to contain any regex metacharacters (which is probably invalid anyway), you would want to match them literally.  Or am I reading the question wrong?

Comment: Keying off this part of the question: `What I would like to do is remove the function, likely with regex` seems like it would require a regex that spans line.

Comment: But as you pointed out, he's processing the file one line at a time,  so the regex never even *sees* the whole function.  Now that you've solved that problem, we can work on a regex to match function definitions.

Comment: That's why you would want to read the script as a single string - IFF you want to use a regex, as in `-replace '<regex>',''` to eliminate the function(s).  That's not to say this couldn't be done on a line-by-line basis.  It's just that the OP specifically questioned the ability of a PowerShell regex to span multiple lines. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a regex that should match an AutoIt function definition.  It assumes the `Func` and `EndFunc` keywords are always placed at the beginning of a line and that they're case sensitive.  The function name is captured in the group named `FuncName` (in C# you would access it via Groups["FuncName"]);

```
"(?m)^Func\s+\b(?<FuncName>_\w+\b).*\n(?:(?!EndFunc\b).*\n)*EndFunc.*\n?"
```

For the function names alone you can use `"\b_\w+\b"` or maybe `"\b_[A-Za-z]+\b"`; I don't know how strict you need to be).  Having almost zero experience with PowerShell, I would probably use `[regex]::Matches` and  `[regex]::Replace` to do the work.  I don't know if PS offers a better way.

I'm assuming you've read the whole file into a string as @Keith suggested, not line by line as you were doing originally.